# Macbook Pro backlight control not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: brightness, macbook, backlight

I'm trying to fix the backlight issue on my Macbook Pro Retina after installing Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is the backlight dimmer buttons <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> are not working at all after installing Ubuntu 16.04.

I have run in some answers that recommends to set the `acpi_backlight=vendor` on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameter and rebooting it and still not working.

Also I've tried this other workaround https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/  but the `ls /sys/class/backlight/` directory returns different files, I've also tried to set some configuration similar to the one proposed on the link but then I got an error at booting Ubuntu on the graphics card.

Have anybody figured this out?

Comment: Intel or Nvidia gpu?

Answer (score 3):

1. In the Terminal application enter:

> ```
> sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf
> ```

2. Paste:

> ```
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier     "Device0"
>     Driver         "nvidia"
>     VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
>     BoardName      "[GPU]"
>     Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
> EndSection
> ```

3. In a new terminal tab (Control + T) or window enter:

> lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'

4. In the first terminal substitude the word [GPU] for the name between brackets shown in the second terminal, leaving out the brackets.
5. Save the document in the first terminal (Control + O), and reboot the computer.

Comment: Leads to screen blanking, I could not get passed boot screen. So definitely not a solution for `GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition`

Comment: Worked in GeForce 9400M in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Doesn't work for GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition in Arch Linux

Comment: Didn't work for GeForce 9400M on a MacBook 2008 with LinuxMint 19.1.  Did you set your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to some special value by any chance?

Comment: I returned the computer to the owner, so I cannot check.

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the `setpci` command to `/etc/rc.local` worked, but only after I also added the shebang `#!/bin/sh` and made the file executable. This could be the reason why that solution doesn't work for people in whose systems `rc.local` didn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful:

```
# grab copy of source
curl -O https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.8.7.tar.xz
tar xf linux-4.8.7.tar.xz
cd linux-4.8.7/drivers/platform/x86

# patch it
curl -o file.patch https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=218051
patch apple-gmux.c < file.patch

# build it
echo '
obj-m += apple-gmux.o

all:
  make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
  make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
' > Makefile
make

# install
targetDir="/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/platform/x86"
sudo cp ${targetDir}/apple-gmux.ko ${targetDir}/apple-gmux.ko.backup
sudo cp apple-gmux.ko ${targetDir}

reboot
```

Source: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105051#c37

Comment: patch was applied in kernel v 4.16 FWIW...