# I want to remap my keyboard to work like my Macbook Air, but I have tried and can't seem to - how do i do it?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook

Hi so I recently got rid of my MacOS since it was a bit broken and switched to Ubuntu. Love Ubuntu so far but I've struggled to figure out how to make my keyboard act like my old keyboard, my keyboard layout is:

[image: my keyboard layout]

I want to also make it so that to change brightness for instance I have to press the function key before the f keys (like fn+f1, fn+f2) and also to do command c and command v instead of pressing ctrl. I did see a few ways in doing this but the solutions I found weren't for the exact keyboard that I have and were slightly different and wouldn't work as intended. Generally I just want my keyboard to act like a macbook keyboard. Thanks in advance.

Still looking for a solution!

Comment: Added complete information about your dream on the MacBook Air key layout on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Ill try it out now and let you know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Came here looking for the opposite! How to get this Mac to map to the same as Linux :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way which I found to remap the keys with mac layout was by installing the app [Kinto](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto).
After the installation, you can use mac os keyboard shortcuts with command key on Linux/Windows

https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto.git
cd kinto
./setup.py
```

Reference: https://youtu.be/kd4al45XD1g

[image]

Comment: This seems like a much easier way to do things! Thank you

Comment: It works like a charm. NOTE, you might need to install `gnome-shell-extentsion-appindicator` and enable TrayIcon. Please follow the instruction at the end of the Kinto install script.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea about remapping keyboard layout by ready-made clothing. Luckily, Macs have a set of layouts.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then you see the Macbook Pro layout, select it and determine whether the mod keys like fn+F1 works as you expected, if not, use the following methods to get what you want.

```
xev
```

This command tells you when the key or mouse button was pressed or released. Take a note of the number and identify what code is set to the key.

I will omit the brightness shortcut issue and give the link already tells better than my description, see [How to change the shortcut to adjust brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34979/how-to-change-the-shortcut-to-adjust-brightness)
also [Macbook Pro backlight control not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812734/macbook-pro-backlight-control-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)

To swap the Control key and the Super(Command) key:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open tweak tool and
[image: Swap ctrl and super]

Then your command (super_L) key is working as control_L thus you can copy and paste with the Mac-like shortcut in real keyboard, but please remember the key is no longer a super_L key, when the instruction is given e.g. use control + any key, you have to remind control key is on the left command key. Enjoy your day!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried to do this after seeing your response and tried with multiple layouts under Macbook/Macbook Pro but when i do 'xev' there is no detected input for Fn so it doesn't show that i pressed it.