# What are the appropriate keyboard setting in Ubuntu for MacBookAir 7,2 (2015)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mac, macbook-air

I just installed Ubuntu (22.04.3) on my 2015 MacBookAir (German keyboard). Sadly various keyboard shortcuts don't work the same as in MacOS.
Has anyone had experience changing the keyboard settings to this specific model?

E.g. 'right-click' does not work as it does on MacOS with 'ctrl + click', copy and paste options don't work as they do on MacOS with 'cmd + c or v' respectively. Same for select all text via 'cmd + a'.

Ideally it should all be identical to the layout I've been used to on MacOS. So far I've only been able to change clipboard settings for terminal, but nothing else.

The keyboard seems to be somewhat distinct since opting for the keyboard layout 'german Macintosh' yields a similar, but not identical layout and functionality as when I'm using my keyboard on MacOS.

Is it possible to change the clipboard settings and right click combinations manually and if so, how?

Comment: Please let us know if any of the answers of this question work for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216796/i-want-to-remap-my-keyboard-to-work-like-my-macbook-air-but-i-have-tried-and-ca, especially https://askubuntu.com/a/1325625/124466

Comment: Installing Kinto worked for the most part (so that I personally feel comfrtable with teh layout). However, setting new short cuts for right-click and alternate keys had to be done via 'Activities>Settings>Accessibility>Click Assist' and Activities>Settings>Keyboard>Alternate Characters Key' respectively. The solution worked well for me because the amount of change I need to get used to is acceptable.

Comment: Can you add this comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1325625/124466) so that it helps other users in future?

Comment: I can’t yet because I don’t have enough reputation points.